# How many Bitcoins could I mine per month

Tags: gpu, bitcoin

I was curious about Bitcoin mining, and I was wondering how many Bitcoins I could mine in a month with a 50 GTX 980 TI.

If anyone has any good links on where to start off in terms of research that would be great, as what I have found on Google is quite confusing.

Comment: Probably not enough to cover the cost of the power.

Comment: Try http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Also. You wouldn't want to mine Bitcoins with a Graphics card look at other alt coins for better profit.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to download a Bitcoin miner (such as [GUIMiner](https://guiminer.org/)) and see how many hashes per second can your PC mine.

However, right now is quite difficult to earn profits as a particular with a common PC, because the difficulties are really high and the relationship earnings/expenses will probably make you loose money every month, because of the power, hardware and maintenance costs.

There are websites (like [this](http://www.coinwarz.com/calculators/bitcoin-mining-calculator) one) that makes an estimation of the profits (or losses) you can get, by entering some basic parameters, like how much do you pay per kWh and how many hashes are you able to mine per second.